# Home Sales question in Home Improvement SE

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I'm new to home Improvement and have a rather specific question I need answered. I am not sure, however, if it is off topic.

In summary, I'm looking for some advice on selling my house during the off/slower season for home sales. I need to know what kinds of things people look for during the off season, and what kinds of projects or things I can do to improve my odds of selling the house.

Home Improvement seems pretty far from what I'm asking, but it is certainly the closest on the site. So, should I ask my question here, or look elsewhere? Also is there another SE, or website that you would recommend for this kind of question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the place for that type of question, and I don't know of any SE sites where that question would be on topic.

You should contact a local real estate agent, as they'll have more detailed information based on your specific location.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the quick response